# How to update a different value for each row?

Tags: postgresql, join, sql-update

I have a postgres table of `predicted_data`:

```
 id | lat | lon | predicted
----+-----+-----+-----------
  1 |   1 |   1 |         10
  2 |   2 |   2 |         20
  3 |   3 |   3 |         30
```

I have another table of `observed_data`:

```
 id | lat | lon | observed | error
----+-----+-----+----------+-------
  1 |   1 |   1 |       11 |
  2 |   2 |   2 |       25 |
  3 |   3 |   3 |       32 |
```

I want to populate the `error` column of `observed_data`. For the first row, I would do:

```
UPDATE observed_data 
SET error = 
((SELECT predicted FROM predicted_data WHERE lat = 1 AND lon = 1) - (SELECT observed FROM observed_data WHERE lat = 1 AND lon = 1)) 
WHERE lat = 1 AND lon = 1 AND id = 1;
```

Is there some way I can write this query so that I do this for every single row at once?

My final outcome should be:

```
 id | lat | lon | observed | error
----+-----+-----+----------+-------
  1 |   1 |   1 |       11 |    -1
  2 |   2 |   2 |       25 |    -5
  3 |   3 |   3 |       32 |    -2
```

Comment: These should be consolidated into a single table. Your current structure is not normalized properly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use an UPDATE with a join:

```
update observed_data as od
  set error = pd.predicted - od.observed
from predicted_data as pd 
where (pd.lat, pd.long) = (od.lat, od.long);
```